# building netcat on windows, edit argv arguments in sourcecode

Tags: c, windows, program-entry-point, netcat

i want to change the source code of the netcat application on windows.
The goal is to declare the arguments in the source code and build it, so i just need to start the program 
and it is working.

The first lines of the source code are the following:

```
main (argc, argv)
int argc;
char ** argv;
```

And I want to change it like

```
argv = "commandline arguments":
```

I've tried it (very long) with different solutions
But it doesn't work
I think I need a solution with a pointer... but of course I'm not sure.

Comment: So what you're saying is you don't want to pass arguments on the command line but instead set defaults for the inside the program?

Comment: C or C++? Pick one...

Comment: Please, don't use K&R-style function definitions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an array of pointers to mutable strings, terminated with `NULL`.  Remember also that `argv[0]` represents the program name, not a supplied argument.  For example, if you want netcat to behave as if it was invoked with the command `nc -l -p 80`, you could do:

```
char arg0[] = "nc";
char arg1[] = "-l";
char arg2[] = "-p";
char arg3[] = "80";
char *fixed_argv[] = { arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3, NULL };

argc = 4;
argv = fixed_argv;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works!
I found out that this wasnt the problem, I have a solution before but i want to use the -e option which wasnt included in the source, but in the exe file it was, so it couldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

`argv` holds an array of pointers to the strings themselves:

```
char *my_argv[] = {
    "arg 0",
    "arg 1",
    "arg 2",
    "...",
    "arg N",
    NULL
};

int my_argc = N;
```

From there, it's generally easiest to rename the existing `main` to some other name, then create a new `main` that calls the renamed version:

```
int main(){ 
    // argv & argc from above

    return renamed_main(my_argc, my_argv);
}
```

Comment: `argv` is supposed to be `NULL` terminated, and the strings themselves must be mutable (so string literals are not suitable).

Comment: @caf: yes, that's how the startup code is required to do things. Unless the original `main` is truly insane, neither is really required. Adding a NULL terminator is easy enough you might as well, but making the strings mutable is foolish unless you truly need it (in which case, as already noted, the existing code is truly insane, and is what really should be rewritten).

Comment: It's easy to imagine code whose command line arguments are all case-insensitive, and so converts the arguments strings in-place to lower case in order to use `strcmp()` to compare them...

Comment: @caf: I can *imagine* all sorts of insanity--but it's still insanity, beyond any reasonable doubt.